# Return a subarray with a value changed to reflect parent object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to change the value of single key in an associative array which is inside another assoc array using javascript.
I have an array like this:

```
let arr = [{
    id: 4,
    name: 'test',
    docs: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'abc'
      },{
        id: 2,
        name: 'xyz'
    }]
}, {
    id: 8,
    name: 'test2',
    docs: [{
        id: 5,
        name: 'abc'
      },{
        id: 7,
        name: 'xyz'
    }]
}]
```

I want to change the value of name of xyz to xyz (test), where test is name key of parent object and get final array as Output:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc (test)'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'xyz (test)'
},
{
    id: 5,
    name: 'abc (test2)'
},
{
    id: 7,
    name: 'xyz (test2)'
}]
```

I am using approach.

```
let docs = new Array();
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    let docx = item.documents.map(item1 => {
        item1.name = item1.name + " ("+item.name+")"; 
    });
    docs.push(docx);
});
return docs;
```

this is returning array of undefined array.

Comment: I have production code, I am trying to put minimal reproducible example without putting the actual code of db structure here. I think the array should be gtg now.

Comment: Anyone have any idea, I am trying to do this without multiple for or foreach loops.

Comment: I am very sorry, bit disturbed today. I have noticed my mistake and updated the output array as you said. Please last time check. I promise you will find it proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a flatMap

```js
let arr = [{ id: 4, name: 'test', docs: [{ id: 1, name: 'abc' },{ id: 2, name: 'xyz' }] }, { id: 8, name: 'test2', docs: [{ id: 5, name: 'abc' },{ id: 7, name: 'xyz' }] }]
const output = arr.flatMap(item =>
  item.docs.map(({id,name}) => ({ id, name: `${name} (${item.name})` }))
)
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Can you check the question, I have updated the output.

Comment: test is not static but name of the parent array object.

Comment: Can you please check the final output? The array is still inside the parent object, I want it inside as a separate array.

Comment: @AbhimanuSharma Ok, I shortened it  - it generates your output now

Answer (score -2):

There is an issue in your data, the `docs` inner array contains an object with duplicate keys:

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 4,
    name: 'test',
    docs: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'abc',
        id: 2,      // <-- duplicate key
        name: 'xyz' // <-- duplicate key
    }]
},
```

If I remove the duplication, you can use this code to create a **new** object with the `name` value updated to `xyz123` if the original value was `xyz`:

```js
const original = [{
  id: 4,
  name: 'test',
  docs: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'xyz'
  }]
}, {
  id: 8,
  name: 'test2',
  docs: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'xyz'
  }]
}];

const updates = original.map(currentObject => {
  const newObject = Object.assign(currentObject);
  const newDocs = newObject.docs.map(doc => {
    const newDoc = Object.assign(doc);
    if (newDoc.name === "xyz") {
      newDoc.name = "xyz123";
    }
    return newDoc;
  });
  newObject.docs = newDocs;
  return newObject
});

console.log(updates);
```